# Free memory that may be malloc'd for the name and argv fields

Tags: c

```
void cleanup( command_t* p_cmd ){
}
```

Basically i need to find a way to free up space that has been `malloc` in C. I am new to c and working on a basic shell.

Comment: You mean the `free` function?

Comment: The `argv` second argument to `main` is *not* made of `malloc`-ed stuff, but of data sitting on the stack (of the `execve`-d process); it might be `malloc`-ed by your code in the *parent* process (your shell).

Comment: You can only free what you yourself have malloc'ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) free (p_cmd);

2) p_cmd = NULL;

E.g.:

```
  void cleanup( command_t* p_cmd )
  {
      if( p_cmd )
      {
          free (p_cmd);
          p_cmd = NULL;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the naive answer. It assumes that command was allocated with a single `malloc()` or `strdup()`...

```
void cleanup(command_t *command) {
    free(command);
}
```

As a matter of style I would call your function something like `free_command()` or `destroy_command()` and keep it near to the functions that allocates the memory in the first place. E.g...

```
typedef char command_t;

command_t *create_command_from_stdin(int line_length) {
    command_t *command = malloc(line_length + 1);
    fgets(command, line_length, stdin);
    command[line_length] = '\0';
    return command;
}

void free_command(command_t *command) {
    free(command);
}
```

You cannot free something twice without trouble. If you fail to free something `malloc()`'d then you get a memory leak. To avoid this, you often keep the create and free functions in the same scope so you don't lose track of them...

```
void shell(void) {
    while(true) {
        command_t *command = create_command(80);
        do_something_with_command(command);
        do_insane_things_with_command(command);
        free_command(command);
    }
}

void do_something_with_command(const command_t *command) { ... }

void do_insane_things_with_command(const command_t *command) { ... }
```

The `const` tag will protect you from accidently freeing them inside the functions and also acts as a hint to others that these functions do not take ownership of the command. That is, they do not take on the responsibility of freeing the memory.

yours, Marcus